# Configure asp.net mvc hocalhost/Products.aspx to hocalhost/Products

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to configure asp.net mvc routing to redirect permanently 301

hocalhost/Products.aspx and hocalhost/Search.aspx

to

hocalhost/Products and hocalhost/Search

i.e. to remove **.aspx** extension from the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick. Map the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Redirect route", "{file}.aspx", 
    new { controller = "home", action = "redirect" });
```

And define a `Redirect` action in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
    // use Request.RawUrl, for instance to parse out what was invoked

    // this regex will extract anything between a "/" and a ".aspx"
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=/).+(?=\.aspx)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var action = regex.Match(Request.RawUrl);

    return RedirectToActionPermanent(action.Value);
}
```

You could redirect both `aspx` pages to the same redirect route and detect which file has actually been invoked by parsing `HttpContext.Request.RawUrl` (there might be a better way for this last point though).

**UPDATE**

There is indeed a simpler way, as found out by @alex himself. In order to get the file in the original request, just do:

```
string file = RouteData.Values["file"].ToString();
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But we need a more general solution, since. aspx pages can be many.

Comment: @alex - how about using a parameter in the url definition? I've updated my answer to reflect what I mean.

Comment: @alex - I've just tried this route and it worked: I set a breakpoint on the `Redirect` method and it breaks in there *for every .aspx request I do*. I've also added a suggestion on how to parse the `Request.RawUrl`. When you say it doesn't work, do you get any error?

Comment: @alex - Done. I've also fixed the Regex; I had a typo in there.

Comment: I can not understand, but Support.aspx does not enter in the Redirect action :(

Comment: @alex - When I said "Done" in the comment above I meant that I had actually already mailed you the test project. You should receive it any minute now.

Comment: Done! This is caching problem.